# Android - TextView ellipsize doesn't work properly

Tags: android, textview

Android ellipsize doesn't work as expected in some cases.
What I'm expecting is three dots on the last line, but in cases it adds the 3 lines plus a few characters related to the rest of the text afterward. Is it possible to change this behavior?

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Show your **whole** layout!

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Whole layout is not needed. This is a TextView specific issue. -1? Sorry that you don't have the answer to my question

Comment: Is the erroneous following text part of the contents of this same TextView?  If so, then yes you have provided enough.  I think Marcin's thought was that it could be text from some *other* UI element.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes the screenshot contains the end of the TextView, and this happens in multiple places in the app regardless of the layout. Event just a single TextView inside a FrameLayout causes this issue.

Comment: Are you using the standard system font? I've had issues in the past with custom fonts and the ellipsis before

Comment: Try `android:ellipsize="marquee"`.

Comment: Try android:maxWidth="width"

Comment: Using standard font. marquee didn't do the trick. I can't set maxWidth because I'm supporting screen rotation, and I need the textView to resize itself

Answer (score 0):

According to me android:ellipsize="end" depends on the words in the TextView.

If following word is lengthy then it omits the word and shows ...

If the following word is small then it will fit correctly and last fill ...

Hope it helps.